# undefined TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, expo, multer

routes.js

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./Upload/Images",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    return cb(
      null,
      //file.originalname
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
      //`${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 900000,
  },
});

petRoute.route("/addpets").post(upload.single("imgforsell"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);

  //var img = fs.readFileSync(req.body.path);
  var encode_image = img.toString("base64");

  const pet = new petModel({
    name: req.body.name,
    title: req.body.title,
    contact: req.body.contact,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    selectedcat: req.body.selectedcat,
    selectedcity: req.body.selectedcity,
    imgforsell: Buffer.from(encode_image, "base64"),
    //imgforsell:req.body.imgforsell,
    contentType: req.file.mimetype,
  });

  pet
    .save() // img
    .then((img) => {
      //img.id
      res.json(img.id);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //remove return and curly braces
      return res.json(err);
    });
});
```

I am trying to build a mern stack application using React-native expo.In this application I am trying to store an image as buffer data in mongo database which stores image name as binary format mongodb and I mage is being upload to static folder in root folder.This above code work fine with Postman but when I try to add data with Physical device it give two error on backend:

undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

on Frontend:
Request failed with status code 500

I am using axios to post data

frontend.js

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Picker,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  input
} from "react-native";

//const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//router.use(bodyParser.json());
//router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import ImagePickerExample from "../components/CameraFunc";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';



export default class Sellnow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangePetName = this.onChangePetName.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetTitle = this.onChangePetTitle.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetContact = this.onChangePetContact.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetPrice = this.onChangePetPrice.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetDescription = this.onChangePetDescription.bind(this);
    this.onValueChangeCat= this.onValueChangeCat.bind(this);
    this.onValueChangeCity= this.onValueChangeCity.bind(this);
    this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this);
   // this.pickImage = this.pickImage.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    // State
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat:"",
      selectedcity:"",
      imgforsell:"",

      //collection categories
      category: [
        
        {
          itemName: "Select Category...."
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Food"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Products"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Accessories"
        }
      ],

      // cities category
      cityCategory:[


        {
          itemName: "Select City...."
        },
        {
          itemName: "Islamabad"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Rawalpindi"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Lahore"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Peshawar"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Karachi"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Quetta"
        }

      ]
    };
  }


  /*componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/PetsBazar/pets/' )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          name: res.data.name,
          title: res.data.title,
          contact: res.data.contact
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }*/
  onChangePetName(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetTitle(e) {
    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetContact(e) {
    this.setState({ contact: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetPrice(e) {
    this.setState({ price: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetDescription(e) {
    this.setState({ description: e.target.value });
  }
  // categories function
  onValueChangeCat(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedcat: e.targetvalue })
  }

  // city function
  onValueChangeCity(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedcity: e.targetvalue })
  }

  onFileChange(e) {
    this.setState({ imgforsell: e.target.files[0] })}

  // uploading Image


  _getPhotoLibrary = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      base64: true,
      exif: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    });

    

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ imgforsell: result });
      
      
    }
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      imgforsell: this.state.imgforsell
    });
  };



  onSubmit  (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /*const petsObject = {
      name: this.state.name,
      title: this.state.title,
      contact: this.state.contact,
      price: this.state.price,
      description: this.state.description,
      selectedcat:this.state.selectedcat,
      selectedcity:this.state.selectedcity,
      imgforsell:this.state.imgforsell
      };
*/
      const formData = new FormData();
      /*formData.append( 'imgforsell', {
    
       // name: new Date() + '_profile',
        uri: this.state.imgforsell,
        type: 'image/jpg',
       
      });*/

      
      formData.append("name", this.state.name);
      formData.append("title", this.state.title);
      formData.append("contact", this.state.contact);
      formData.append("price", this.state.price);
      formData.append("description", this.state.description);
      formData.append("selectedcat", this.state.selectedcat);
      formData.append("selectedcity", this.state.selectedcity);
      formData.append("imgforsell", this.state.imgforsell);


      
      


      fetch(
        `http://${
          Platform.OS === "android" ? "192.168.10.11" : "localhost"
        }:4000/pets/addpets`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        }
      )
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(res);
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({
            name: "",
            title: "",
            contact: "",
            price: "",
            description: "",
            selectedcat: "",
            selectedcity: "",
            imgforsell: "",
          });
        });
  }



  

  render() {
   
    const {imgforsell} = this.state
    
  
   
    return (
      <View>
      <ScrollView
        nestedScrollEnabled={true}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.conText}>Please Fill the Below Form </Text>

            <View style={styles.borderForm}>
              <Text style={styles.formText}>Your Name</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                multiline
                placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"
                maxLength={15}
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onChangePetName}
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
              />

              <Text style={styles.formText}>Category</Text>

             { /*<CategoryDropList />*/ }

             <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            
             <Picker
          
           itemStyle={styles.itemStyle}
            mode="dropdown"
           style={styles.pickerStyle}
            selectedValue={this.state.selectedcat}
           // onValueChange={this.onValueChangeCat.bind(this)}
           //onValueChange={(selectedcat)=>this.setState({selectedcat})}
           onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex)=> this.setState({selectedcat:itemValue})}
        
          >
            {this.state.category.map((item, index) => (
              <Picker.Item
               
                color="black"
                label={item.itemName}
                value={item.itemName}
                index={index}
              />
            ))}
          </Picker>
         
          </View>

              

              <Text style={styles.formText}>Pet/Product Title</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                placeholder="Enter Product Title"
                maxLength={15}
                value={this.state.title}
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                onChange={this.onChangePetTitle}
                onChangeText={(title) => this.setState({ title })}
              />

              <Text style={styles.formText}>City</Text>

              {/*<CityDropList />*/}

              <View style={styles.viewStyle}>

              <Picker
          
           itemStyle={styles.itemStyle}
            mode="dropdown"
           style={styles.pickerStyle}
            selectedValue={this.state.selectedcity}
           onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex)=> this.setState({selectedcity:itemValue})}
        
          >
            {this.state.cityCategory.map((item, index) => (
              <Picker.Item
               
                color="black"
                label={item.itemName}
                value={item.itemName}
                index={index}
              />
            ))}
          </Picker>

          

          </View>
              <Text style={styles.formText}> Contact Number </Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                placeholder="Phone Number"
                inputType="number"
                maxLength={11}
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                value={this.state.contact}
                onChange={this.onChangePetContact}
                onChangeText={(contact) => this.setState({ contact })}
              />
              <Text style={styles.formText}>Price</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.formInput}
                multiline
                placeholder="Enter Price"
                inputType="number"
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                maxLength={7}
                value={this.state.price}
                onChange={this.onChangePetPrice}
                onChangeText={(price) => this.setState({ price })}
              />
              <Text style={styles.formText}>Image of Product</Text>

              {/*<ImagePickerExample />*/}

             

              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this._getPhotoLibrary.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.btnTxt}> Choose File</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity>
        
                {imgforsell ? (
              <Image source={{ uri: imgforsell.uri }} style={styles.uploadimgstyle} />
            ) : (
              <View/>
            )}
            
              
              <Text style={styles.formText}>
                Description(Optional max 150 words)
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.descriptionInput}
                multiline
                placeholder="Describe your product"
                maxLength={150}
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                value={this.state.description}
                onChange={this.onChangePetDescription}
                onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({ description })}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this.onSubmit}>
                <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Submit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

//export default withRouter(Sellnow);

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
  },

  sellText: {
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },

  formContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff9933",
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  conText: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "left",
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
  },

  formInput: {
    //flex:1,
    height: 50,
    // marginLeft:7,
    //marginRight:7,
    fontSize: 18,
    margin: 10,
    width: 350,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    textAlign: "left",
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
  formText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "left",
    margin: 10,
  },
  descriptionInput: {
    height: 80,
    margin: 10,
    width: 340,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    textAlign: "left",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
  },
  borderForm: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#FF642E",
    margin: 7,

    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
  },
  btn: {
    margin: 20,
    height: 35,
    width: 120,
    backgroundColor: "#FF642E",
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  btnTxt: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "white",
    margin: 5,
  },
  dropdown: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
  },
  dropdownContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ff9933",
    padding: 8,
  },
  itemStyle: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular",
    color: "black",
    
    
    
  },
  pickerStyle: {
    width: "73%",
    height: 40,
    color: "black",
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular",
    //marginLeft:-100,
   // alignItems:"flex-start"

},
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular",
    textAlign:'left'

    
  },
  viewStyle: {
    // flex: 1,
     alignSelf: "center",
     flexDirection: "row",
     width: "140%",
     justifyContent: "space-between",
     alignItems: "flex-start",
     borderWidth:1,
     height:'5%',
     backgroundColor:'white',
     borderRadius:10,
     margin:7
   },
   uploadimgstyle:{

    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    margin:5,
    resizeMode:'cover',
    alignSelf:'center'

   }
});
```

Comment: If it works with Postman but not with your React Native client, then the problem is probably with your frontend code

Comment: I have edited the code above by adding front end code

Comment: Where is the file supposed to come from? Do you have a file picker element? How does its `File` value get into your component state?

Comment: I am using expo image picker to pick file  here you can see my complete code with front end and backend https://snack.expo.dev/@saadshaoorghazanfar/430811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're calling Axios is the problem. The signature for the [post method](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) is

> `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

With your code, that's

```js
axios.post(
  /* url    */ Platform.OS === "android" ? "http://192.168.10.11:4000/pets/addpets" : "http://localhost:4000/pets/addpets",
  /* data   */ petsObject,
  /* config */ formData
)
```

so you're passing the `FormData` as the `config` object.

You cannot mix `application/json` and `multipart/form-data` in the same request. Instead, you need to build up `FormData` with all the parameters you need. When uploading a file, you also need to append the `File` instance and not an object with `uri` and `type` properties.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
// append the File
formData.append("imgforsell", this.state.imgforsell);

// append other data
formData.append("name", this.state.name);
formData.append("title", this.state.title);
// etc...

axios
  .post(
    `http://${
      Platform.OS === "android" ? "192.168.10.11" : "localhost"
    }:4000/pets/addpets`,
    formData
  )
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.toJSON());
    // res.status(500).json(err)  don't do this, it's not Express
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat: "",
      selectedcity: "",
      imgforsell: "",
    });
  });
```

---

If Axios doesn't work (because I've seen patchy reports about file uploads in React Native), you can substitute it with `fetch`

```js
fetch(
  `http://${
    Platform.OS === "android" ? "192.168.10.11" : "localhost"
  }:4000/pets/addpets`,
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  }
)
  .then((res) => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(res);
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat: "",
      selectedcity: "",
      imgforsell: "",
    });
  });
```

Comment: @SaadChaudry could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71964254/edit) your question to show what you changed?

Comment: I have edited question and front end error has changend to " Network request failed  "

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: yes i have checked twice

Comment: By using axios i am able to log data in console but its not posting in server or mongo db any fix please?